# Allow members to set their own localization preferences? NO - date shows hour

Tags: low-nice-date

After setting Allow members to set their own localization preferences? NO in Member > Preferences the member_birthday in a zoo visitors edit form shows hours:

BEFORE: 30/11/2000
AFTER: 30/11/2000 00:00

I'm using excelent low nice date to format the date in the form like this:
{exp:low_nice_date date="{member_birthday}" localize="no" format="%d/%m/%Y"}
(even tried localize="yes")

but 00:00 are still there?

Any help on this?

Comment: EE version, please? And can you clean up your question a little? It's a little confusing in a grammatical sense.

Comment: Does turning on the template debugger give you any insight? Also, I'd recommend using a 2000-11-30 date format as input, as that is unambiguous. EE (and PHP) can consider a format with slashes as MM/DD/YYYY.